# Происхождение слова "вкупе"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Почему мы говорим "вкупе"? Что это дословно значит? Каково происхождение этого слова?

Answer (score 3):

Вкупе - это наречие со значением "вместе", например: "И вот все члены нашей семьи, все вкупе, как один человек, принялись за приготовления к спектаклю"

Заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз. Сращение предлога В и сущ. "купа"  со значением «куча, толпа, совокупность», в др.-рус. яз. еще известного.  Общеславянская  основа kupa.

В современном языке слово "купа" считается устаревшим, но еще в словаре Даля отмечены следующие варианты его употребления: Вали в одну купу! Деревья стоят купами, с прогалинами. Под липою стоит купка овец. Мраморная купа.

Хотя сами слова (вкупе и купа) уходят из языка, они интересны своими родственными связями: один и тот же корень имеют такие известные слова, как копна, копить, скопом, совокупность.
К примеру, слово копить образовано от "копа" - древняя мера в 60 единиц, сравнить: kopiti (чешск.) - сгребать, складывать кучей.

Comment: >Хотя сами слова (вкупе и купа) уходят из языка (...)

К примеру на Украине слова *"купа"* и *"купка"* (соотв. "куча" и "кучка") широко употребляются и на сегодняшний день.

Answer (score 1):

Коли уж вопрос всплыл, добавлю свои пять копеек к ответу Софии.
Слова "купно" и подобные действительно становятся весьма редкими. Но сам корень в неизменном значении никуда не делся. Совокупно, совокупление - это та самая совместность, которая задает семантический ряд разбираемому слову.

И еще одна реплика. "Скупщина" - так в Югославии (а на местном уровне - и сейчас в Сербии) именовались выборные органы власти Югославии, парламент - и ниже. К "скупке" отношения, понятно, не имеет, "купить" - это вообще совершенно другой по происхождению корень, позднее заимствование. А вот к "совокупности" - вполне.